# How to exclude dash from React input type="number"

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs

I am using input type="number" in the react.
I only want numbers to be allowed when I write text and I don't want dash to go in.
However, running my code will allow me to write dash with numbers.
How do I make all special characters, including dash, possible only numbers?

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aSxxS.png)

This is my code.

```js
const [localValue, setLocalValue] = useState<string>('')
const handleChange = useCallback(
  event => {
    const numberOnlyStr = (vaule: string) => vaule === '' || /^[0-9\b]+$/.test(vaule)
    if (!numberOnlyStr(event.target.value)) {
      return
    }
    event.target.value = newValue
    setLocalValue(newValue)
  },
  [setLocalValue],
)

return (
  <input
    type="text"
    name="text"
    id="input-text"
    value={localValue}
    onChange={handleChange}
  />
)
```

Comment: Instead of return in callback use event.stopPropagation()

Comment: use regex or use regex with react-hook-form

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've used this before. Maybe this will help you.

```
  <input
        type="text"
        inputMode="numeric"
        placeholder="Value"
        value={value}
        onChange={handleChange}
  />

const [value, setValue] = useState("");
const handleChange = evt => {
    const newValue = evt.target.value.replace(
        /[^a-zA-Z\s]/g,
        ""
    );
    setValue(newValue);
};
```

Comment: Not sure how this is the answer. The question title asks for `type="number"` but the answer uses `text`. onChange isn't called when only a `-` is entered in `number` inputs